# iOS when is the parent controller available in UIContainerView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to access the parent controller from a container. When I do this:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad{
    if(self.parentViewController){
        NSLog(@"Parent here!"); //Never gets called
    }
}
```

De NSLog never gets called. I moved this piece of code to viewWillLayoutSubViews. Is this the correct place?

Comment: how do you add it to container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is called when your view is created and accessed for the first time, that can happen before your new view controller is added to the container parent, so that's the reason in the viewDidLoad the parent is still nil

Comment: That sounds very logical, but when Should I try to access the parent?

Comment: In the viewDidAppear / viewWillAppear for example